# How to correct set v-model with computed method in Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I got an component:

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="customerComponentModel" />
</template>
<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: Object,
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const customerComponentModel = computed({
      get: () => {
      if (props.modelValue) {
          return props.modelValue.Customer
        } else {
          return ''
        }
      },
      set: (value) => {
           ????
    });

    return { customerComponentModel };
  },
};
</script>
```

This component works fine if i send to it data thru modelValue. How can i set customerComponentModel  value if props.modelValue not set in parent? I want use component in both way - with props and without.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emit an `update:modelValue` event with the new object value. To update only the `Customer` field, the emitted value should be a clone of `props.modelValue` along with a new `Customer` field equal to the new value:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: Object,
  },
  setup(prop, { emit }) {
    const customerComponentModel = computed({
      //...
      set: (value) => {
        emit('update:modelValue', {
          ...props.modelValue,
          Customer: value,
        })
      }
    });

    return {
      customerComponentModel
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/updating-subproperty-with-v-model-object-8vdd4?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue:437-534)